# Pick new routes when new micro-service registers with Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm using Eureka Server where every microservice gets registered as soon it gets online.

Now I want to use Zuul to create a gateway proxy.

Zuul works if I provide routes manually:

```
zuul.routes.ms1.url=http://localhost:8901
zuul.routes.ms2.url=http://localhost:8902
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

I want Zuul to auto pick routes from Eureka as soon new micro-services is up and registered with Eureka.

I tired adding `@EnableAutoDiscovery` to Zuul Initalization class 
and setting `ribbon.eureka.enabled=true` after removing routes but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` in your properties in zuul service, zuul will take **all** services which is registered to eureka server.